# What to return if something failed, rather than return a a 'magic number'?

Tags: language-agnostic

Say I re-implement a method for finding the position of a string within a string. So I get either the position which is an integer, or a "magic number" like -1. I see this pattern in so many programming languages, where some return a value like `null`, some return some random "out of range" value like -`, some totally throw an error.

Is there a "best practice" on this or at least something that's a bit more explicit in other programming language that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

This is not as language agnostic as you make it out to be, it very much depends on the language and the exact purpose of the function. There are pretty much three different approaches:

- throw an exception
- set a flag somewhere which indicates whether an error occurred
- return an "out of range" value

Now:

- Some languages don't have any notion of exceptions, or the "error" is not really that "exceptional".
- Setting error flags may or may not be ideal for the language in question. Go uses this approach by making returning a result and an error indicator the idiomatic default. Javascript has made it partially idiomatic to accept callbacks like `function (result, err)`. For other languages this approach may not be suitable at all.
- "Out of range" values are typical for dynamically typed languages, but can be problematic for statically typed languages.

Whichever works best for the language in question and the specific function needs to be decided individually. The goals need to be weighed between making sense ("string not found" is probably *not* an *exception*), and making it easy to write simple and correct code.

Comment: Aren't out of range values problematic if you want your code to be cleaner? With a flag like Node.js you at least distinguish more explicitly between 2 kinds for results, whereas returning just 'out of range' value packs everything together.

Comment: Sure, that's *an* issue you need to consider. Depending on the language it *can* actually be convenient to lump those together though; e.g. PHP often returns `false` or *a falsey value* which you can treat equally if you want to or can distinguish in more detail when you have to (classic example `strpos(...) === false`). This becomes *very* problematic when a valid return value is somewhat indistinguishable from an error value. For that reason newer languages opt for exceptions/separate err flags.